# Alt (Option) key with left click not selecting all axis on mesh in edit mode

Tags: mesh, vertices, select

I am kind of new to Blender, and I have this reoccurring problem with mesh axis selection in Edit mode. As I am using a MacBook Pro, (with Blender v 3.0), the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for me is the  <kbd>Option</kbd> key on keyboard, however it does not work in some shortcuts inside Blender.

Including the axis snap one - when in *Edit Mode* and I want to easily select the entire axis of my mesh, the  <kbd>Option</kbd> key pressed and left clicking the vertex, does nothing.

How do I fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by "select entire axis of my mesh" !? please make a screenshot or a sketch what you mean

Comment: Remap the shortcut and it should work.